# MVC4: Access controller properties in partial view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to access the property of a base controller from a partial view?

I have the following setup:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private string ServerName
    {
        get
        {
            return Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
        }
    }
    private Entities.Client _Client { get; set; }
    public Entities.Client Client
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Client ?? (this._Client = this.HttpContext.Application["Client"] as Entities.Client);
        }
    }
    private Settings _Settings { get; set; }
    public Settings Settings
    {
        get
        {

            if (this._Settings == null)
            {
                this._Settings = new Settings(this.Client, this.Client.WebPageTemplateCapabilities != null ? SettingsType.XML : SettingsType.SQL);
            }

            return this._Settings;
        }
    }
}
```

All my controllers inherit BaseController, and in some of the views of the child actions of those controllers I render partial views. Is there any way to access BaseController.Settings from one of those partial views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any information needed by the view should either be passed *from* the controller to the view and then further passed down from the view to the partials e.g.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(this.Settings);
}
```

In your view

```
@model Settings

@Html.RenderPartial("SomePartial", Model)
```

In your partial

```
@model Settings

// use settings
```

> All my controllers inherit BaseController, and in some of the views of the child actions of those controllers I render partial views

In that case, you would just need to pass the model in from the controller e.g.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return PartialView("SomePartialView", this.Settings);
}
```

Comment: My controllers return views based on other models already, injecting the Settings object into that model doesn't seem like a practical way to do it, since the only view requiring access to the Settings object is this one partial view in question. Are there any downsides to my answer?

Comment: @Maritim the only downside I would say is you now have your view coupled with your controller which isn't great. However, there is no technical reason why it won't work. My suggestion would be to just update your partial view model to take a reference to the settings as well which would de-couple them.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
@{
    var settings = (ViewContext.Controller as BaseController).Settings;
}
```